# Numero maximo para um campo no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possivel limitar um valor maximo a um campo, ex: quero que o numero maximo de level seja o numero 200 no banco de dados mysql. é possivel isso atraves de um update, de qual forma poderia ser feito isso?

Comment: Dá pra fazer isso antes de enviar ao banco, no proprio PHP, usando uma simples IF `if ($valor <= 200) { mysqli_query('UPDATE ...'); } else { echo 'O tamanho ultrapassou o limite'; }`

Comment: Constraint CHECK. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Não funcionou nenhum dos dois comigo =/

Answer (score -1):

O melhor seria limitar na programação pois o banco de dados vai guardar o mesmo espaço de dados que é no seu caso um numero de 3 dígitos. sendo assim é melhor usar a restrição do valor na mascara de entrada dos dados.